# rsync include not working with directories

Tags: rsync

I a using rsync include successfully if the file is in the root of the source location but not if it is in a directory

This works:

```
 rsync -aP --omit-dir-times \
     -e 'ssh -p100  -i /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' \
     --include fixed.xml --include file2.txt \
     --exclude * \
     /home/me/Desktop/test/ me@192.168.1.10:here/
```

This does not:

```
 rsync -aP --omit-dir-times \
     -e 'ssh -p100  -i /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' \
     --include fixed.xml --include 50/200/file2.txt \
     --exclude * \
     /home/me/Desktop/test/ me@192.168.1.10:here/
```

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case is actually described with examples in the rsync man page.

The solution is include the directories up the file you want:

```
 --include 50 --include 50/200 --include 50/200/file2.txt
```

If this happens a lot then you can just add this, which is a shorter command but will force rsync to scan a lot of directories you don't care about:

```
--include '*/' --prune-empty-dirs --include 50/200/file2.txt
```

The prune is required to prevent it creating the whole directory structure, minus files, but should be used with care.